# Gadgeteer and SPI protocol (Digital potentiometer)

Tags: spi, .net-gadgeteer

I'm trying to create a project that will allow me to control digital potentiometer using the .NET gadgeteer. They both use the SPI protocol so at first sight this should be easy.
The potentiometer is MCP4131:

http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8062/8240194093_87b2e5c9fb.jpg

and the gadgeteer socket is:

Pin 1   Pin 2   Pin 3   Pin 4   Pin 5   Pin 6   Pin 7   Pin 8   Pin 9   Pin 10
+3.3V    +5V     GPIO!   GPIO    GPIO    GPIO    MOSI    MISO    SCK     GND

Unfortunately, I can't understand how to connect these two together.
Furthermore, I Don't really know how to program the gadgeteer in order to control the potentiometer.

Any help would come in handy, 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience controlling SPI (so don't mark this as the answer for at least a few days) but I did find example code showing how to program SPI interfaces through Gadgeteer on the GHI site: http://www.ghielectronics.com/docs/14/spi

It is also worth noting this post on the Gadgeteer CodePlex pointing out that to get the SPI library in 4.2 you need to add a reference to `Gadgeteer.SPI` to the project: http://gadgeteer.codeplex.com/discussions/362536

(N.B. I have not found StackOverflow a useful site to get help on Gadgeteer questions. I hope it gets better. In the mean time I have been posting questions on the GHI Gadgeteer Forum https://www.ghielectronics.com/community/forum/board?id=21 and finding I get useful and knowledgeable answers there.)